# How does one load a json encoded array as the x-axis for c3.js?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, c3.js

Pretty much the title. I have an array of serial numbers that I want to make as the x-axis. The array data itself was sucked up from a database via PHP. I then json_encode'd it and made it into a js array. The problem I'm having is that there is a separate section for both json: and columns: when generating a C3js graph.

```
var jsarray = <?php echo json_encode($array) ?>;
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            x: 'js_array',
            columns: [
                ['x', js_array]
            ],
            json: {
                Data_points,
                Data_points2    
            },
        axis: {
            y: {
                label: { // ADD
                    text: 'Y axis title',
                    position: 'outer-middle'
                }

            }
        }  
});
```

I tried looking for an example in the c3.js documentation, but they have separate sections for JSON data and formatting the x-axis. I didn't see a section where they combined the two though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to be able to label the X-Axis data points while using JSON data, kind of like this example: http://c3js.org/samples/data_stringx.html ?

Assuming you have data in your PHP that looks something like this:

```
$php_data = array(
    'x_labels' => array('MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI'),
    'data1' => array(30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250),
    'data2' => array(50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25)
);
```

...then you should be able to achieve something similar to the example above using JSON data like so:

```
var json_data = <?php echo json_encode($php_data) ?>;
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    data: {
        x: 'x_labels',
        json: json_data
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
          type: 'category'
      },
      y: {
          label: 'number'
      }
    }
});
```

The `data: { x: 'x_labels' }` part tells the library to use the data under the array key "x_labels" at the axis labels, and then under `axis: { x: { type: 'category' } }`, we specify that we want to use strings for the label type rather than numbers. You don't have to specify this if your axis labels are numbers (e.g. `'x_labels' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`).

Here's a jsfiddle if you want to play around with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/WingZero/Ldk4shLz/3/